# Неверно отрабатывает switch

Tags: java

Вот код:

```
char side;
char left = '\u2190';
char up = '\u2191';
char right = '\u2192';
char down = '\u2193';
do {
side = (char) System.in.read();
switch (side) {
    case 'L':
        System.out.println(left);
        break;
    case 'U':
        System.out.println(up);
        break;
    case 'R':
        System.out.println(right);
        break;
    case 'D':
        System.out.println(down);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Неверное значение");
        break;
} while (side != 'Q');
```

Когда ввожу значение, которое есть в case выводит стрелочку, а потом "Неверное значение", где ошибка?

Comment: вывелите в консоль символ, на котором switch вылетел в drfault, я думаю Вы там увидите какой нибудь перевод строки или возврат каретки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После ввода символа вы жмёте клавишу `Enter`, `System.in.read()` расценивает это как еще один символ. Также эта функция вызывает исключение `IOException`, которое нужно обработать.

В таком случае лучше использовать класс `Scanner`. Вот код программы:

```java
char side;
char left = '\u2190';
char up = '\u2191';
char right = '\u2192';
char down = '\u2193';
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    side = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    switch (side) {
        case 'L':
            System.out.println(left);
            break;
        case 'U':
            System.out.println(up);
            break;
        case 'R':
            System.out.println(right);
            break;
        case 'D':
            System.out.println(down);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Неверное значение");
        break;
    }
} while (side != 'Q');
```

Если вам всё-таки нужно использовать `System.in.read()`, то после этого вызовите функцию `System.in.skip(1)` Т. е.:

```java
side = (char) System.in.read();
System.in.skip(1);
```